# Algolia: Custom Searchbox and Clearall

Tags: javascript, html, dom, algolia

I am using Algolia and instantsearch.js for one of my projects.

I managed to get the custom searchbox to work. Inside JS I create an input field and style it to look nice:

```
// searchbox design
var searchField = '<div class="input-search">';
searchField += '<i class="input-search-icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
searchField += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerSearch" name="search" placeholder="Search for customer..">';
searchField += '<span id="custom-clear-all-container"></span>';
searchField += '</div>';

// custom `renderFn` to render the custom SearchBox widget
function renderFnSB(SearchBoxRenderingOptions, isFirstRendering) {
    if (isFirstRendering) {
        SearchBoxRenderingOptions.widgetParams.containerNode.html(searchField);
        SearchBoxRenderingOptions.widgetParams.containerNode
            .find('input')
            .on('keyup', function() {
                SearchBoxRenderingOptions.refine($(this).val());
            });
        SearchBoxRenderingOptions.widgetParams.containerNode
            .find('input')
            .val(SearchBoxRenderingOptions.query);
    }
}

// connect `renderFn` to SearchBox logic
var customSearchBox = instantsearch.connectors.connectSearchBox(renderFnSB);

// mount widget on the page
search.addWidget(
    customSearchBox({
        containerNode: $('#custom-searchbox')
    })
);
```

The code above is almost identical to the code example in Algolia's documentation. I just added a "div" in DOM with id="custom-searchbox". This works just fine.

Then I try to create a custom clear all button and append it to:

```
<span id="custom-clear-all-container"></span>
```

inside searchbox. Again I use an almost identical code as Algolia's documentation:

```
function renderFnCA(ClearAllRenderingOptions, isFirstRendering) {
    var containerNode = ClearAllRenderingOptions.widgetParams.containerNode;

    if (isFirstRendering) {
        var markup = $('<button id="custom-clear-all" type="button" class="input-search-close icon wb-close" aria-label="Close"></button>');
        containerNode.append(markup);

        markup.on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ClearAllRenderingOptions.refine();
        })
    }

    var clearAllCTA = containerNode.find('#custom-clear-all');
    clearAllCTA.attr('disabled', !ClearAllRenderingOptions.hasRefinements)
};

// connect `renderFn` to ClearAll logic
var customClearAllWidget = instantsearch.connectors.connectClearAll(renderFnCA);

// mount widget on the page
search.addWidget(
    customClearAllWidget({
        containerNode: $('#custom-clear-all-container'),
        clearsQuery: true
    })
);
```

When I run the code, everything is working but I don't see the clearAll button (in my case is an X icon).

If I insert the:

```
<span id="custom-clear-all-container"></span>
```

directly into HTML and remove it from JS, then it works perfectly.

I don't know what is going wrong. By the way, the code to add clearAll is after the code for adding the searchbox. So, the searchbox DOM element is already placed in DOM when we are trying to append clearAll button.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to leave the  button in the dom and instead of completely removing it $('#custom-clear-all').hide() it instead.

The algolia search widget is probably looking for the button all the time and when its not found in dom it doesn't run

Comment: I fixed it by adding the "#custom-clear-all-container" span in DOM directly and appending the clearAll button. At the same time i used "prepend" instead of "html" to insert the input field in "#custom-searchbox".